# What is this Wild Grass that randomly grows in 3 spots?

Tags: grass

What is this Wild Grass that randomly grows in 3 spots?

[image]
[image]

Any ideas? Thanks?

Comment: It seems a sort of Carex, but we need better photos (leaves, spikes), and region.